# The difference of closure of a set

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$, $B\subset \mathbb R^N$ be given such that $A\subset B$. Assume that $\mathcal H^{N-1}(B\setminus A)<\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0$ is a fixed constant and $\mathcal H^{N-1}$ is the $N-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure (so we may think $A$ and $B$ are two curves embedded in $\mathbb R^N$). Moreover, we know that $\mathcal H^{N-1}(\overline {B}\setminus B)<\epsilon$ where $\overline{B}$ denotes the closure of set $B$, and $\mathcal H^{N-1}(\bar A\setminus A)=0$.

My question: do we have 
$$
\mathcal H^{N-1}(\overline {B\setminus A})<2\epsilon
$$
hold?

---

Update: I added an assumption on $A$ such that $A$ is compact, i.e., 
$$
\mathcal H^{N-1}(\overline {A}\setminus A^{\circ})=0
$$
where by $A^\circ$ we mean the interior of $A$. That is, I assume that $\mathcal H^{N-1}(\partial A)=0$.

Hence, I may write
\begin{align}
\mathcal H^{N-1}(\overline {B\setminus A})\leq\mathcal H^{N-1}(\overline {\overline {B}\setminus A^\circ}) = \mathcal H^{N-1}( {\overline {B}\setminus A^\circ})\\
\leq\mathcal H^{N-1}( {\overline {B}\setminus B})+\mathcal H^{N-1}( {{B}\setminus A})+\mathcal H^{N-1}( {{A}\setminus A^\circ})\leq 2\epsilon.
\end{align}

PS: I understand that $A^\circ$ might be ill-defined... I am trying to work out a fix.

Comment: How do you prove that $\mathcal H^{N-1}( {\overline {B}\setminus A^\circ})\\
\leq\mathcal H^{N-1}( {\overline {B}\setminus B})+\mathcal H^{N-1}( {{B}\setminus A})+\mathcal H^{N-1}( {{A}\setminus A^\circ})\leq 2\epsilon$?

Comment: @User1006 they are nested, right?

Comment: This is based on $A^o\subset \overline {B}$. If not, it may not be true since $\mathcal H^{N-1}( {\overline {B}\setminus A^o})=\mathcal H^{N-1}( \overline {B})-\mathcal H^{N-1}( {\overline {B}\cap A^\circ})$, while $\mathcal H^{N-1}( {\overline {B}\setminus B})+\mathcal H^{N-1}( {{B}\setminus A})+\mathcal H^{N-1}( {{A}\setminus A^\circ})=\mathcal H^{N-1}( \overline {B})-\mathcal H^{N-1}( A^\circ)$

Comment: @User1006 I noticed. Actually, I don't even sure that $A^\circ$ is well-defined since $A$ is just a curve.

Comment: $A^o$ is always well-defined and is empty for dense set.

Comment: @User1006 Sorry I was out off my apt. Yea sure I understood. Thank you!

Comment: @User1006 of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The answer is no because by formula between closure and boundary
$$
\overline {A}=A\cup (\partial A-A)
$$
We have
$$
\overline {B-A}=(B-A)\cup (\partial (B-A)-(B-A))
$$
Given $\mathcal H^{N-1}(B-A)<\epsilon$, plus $\mathcal H^{N-1}(\overline {B}\setminus B)<\epsilon$ and $\mathcal H^{N-1}(\bar A\setminus A)=0$, it can not prevent measure of $\partial (B-A)$ from getting big, particular if $B-A$ is dense like subset of $\Bbb{Q}$.

**Edit:**

Here is a fix. Just assume $\mathcal H^{N-1}(\partial (B-A))<\epsilon$. Then you can prove it.

Comment: But should you have $\mathcal H^{N-1}(\bar B)=\infty$ in this case?

Comment: What do you think that what condition should I place on $A$ such that the inequality I want would hold?

Comment: I update my post. Please have a look!